# Kendo Grid groupHeaderTemplate not working with complex dataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am trying to use a kendo grid to display complex data. I reconstructed my problem in a simple way using kendo ui dojo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            { 
                field: "name",
                title: 'Name' + ' *',
                template: '#= name.prename #',
                groupHeaderTemplate: 'Test',
            },
            { 
                field: "age",
                title: 'Age' + ' *'
            },

        ],
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            { 
                name: {
                    prename: "Jane",
                    surname: "Doe"
            },
                age: 30 
            },
            { 
                name: {
                    prename: "John",
                    surname: "Doe"
            }, 
                age: 30 
            }
        ],
        group: { field: "name.prename" }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/eDuci/5

The problem is that groupHeaderTemplate should rename the grouping header to "Test" which it does not. Instead it shows "name.prename" and ignores the groupHeaderTemplate.

The next problem is when making grouping configurable, it throws an error when i try to group by such a complex column.

Anybody encountered the same or any similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the column as:

```
{ 
    field: "name.prename",
    title: 'Name' + ' *',
    template: '#= name.prename #',
    groupHeaderTemplate: 'Test'
},
```

i.e. `field` should be the same that you define in `group`.

Your dojo modified here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/ITuVU

Comment: Yes, this is what i am working with currently (without using the template), but this way my custom field validation is not called...

Comment: Which validation? Is it a different problem?